# Airplay over wifi-ethernet bridge

Tags: airplay

I have an IOgear wifi to ethernet bridge, connected to a Marantz AVR without wifi. I can access its (the AVR) web interface through the IP the bridge was assigned, and the changes I make on it show up on the AVR. However, I can't find it on the airplay list of any of my Apple devices (MBP, iPhone, iPad). Is there a way to make this work, or is it impossible?

EDIT: As far as I know, the bridge device does not have a NAT, as it has only one port and I have not found a way to configure stuff relating to that.

Comment: You may need to open ports (port forwarding) in the bridge device if it's acting as NAT, where typically the port 80 is open thus allowing access to the Marantz web interface. Other ports required for the use you intend are probably closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sems to have solved itself. I had tried power cycling and hard resets (on the bridge), but that hadn't done anything. Looks like just waiting solved, although I don't know how...